# How do I get SQL Server agent to show up in SSMS for a non-sysadmin user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I have already mapped the user to the `msdb` database and assigned him the role of `SQLAgentOperatorRole`, but the user still can't see the **SQL Server Agent** listed when he connects.

The **SQL Server Agent** does show up fine when I log in as a `sysadmin`.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server is this?  Were you able to connect to the *same* instance and see SQL Server Agent?  If you could: `select serverproperty('Edition');`

Comment: Yes, definitely the same instance, and I confirmed this by temporarily granting the user sysadmin access. The SQL version is Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit). As a sysadmin, the user does see SQL Agent but as just SQLAgentOperatorRole he does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to consider.

1. Make sure that person connecting to SQL Server 2012 is using SSMS 2012, I have seen compatibility issues when some features are not showing up when connecting with wrong version.
2. Remove all roles from the user and grant them again, go over [these](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190926.aspx) steps to make sure that you have done it correctly first time.

Script for creating account and assigning role:

```
USE [master] 
CREATE LOGIN SQlSATest WITH PASSWORD = 'test', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY= OFF; 
USE [msdb]
CREATE USER [SQLSATest] FROM LOGIN SQLSATest; 
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'SQLAgentOperatorRole', @membername = 'SQLSATest'
```

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Wiki answer based on comments originally left by the question author:</sub>*

The problem on the original account was that I set SQL to hide all databases from the user (since the user in question is not an employee, and we have NDAs with many clients, the name of some databases are considered sensitive in some cases (the name of our clients for example)):

```
use master 
GO 
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [myuser]; 
GO
```

and that also hides SQL Agent unfortunately. I wanted tol hide the databases and leave SQL Agent.

I worked around it by creating a new instance for this user.

Answer (score -3):

Page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles says "A user must be a member of one of these fixed database roles or a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to use SQL Server Agent."

So you SHOULD not need to be a member of the sysadmin role to see SQL Server Agent.  Other questions on SA say that sysadmin is required though.  Maybe it's a SQL Server or SSMS bug...

Comment: This doesn't really provide a clear answer to the question beyond the answer that was already accepted.

Comment: In fact, OP eventually determined that it was a cross effect of `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [myuser]` for the user in question; he needed to prevent this user from seeing the name of any of the databases. So, not a bug in SQL or SSMS.